# Error while importing compass/css3

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css and I am trying to import compass/css3 file into my css code but it is showing an error "fail to load resource". How to resolve it ?

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

Comment: can you share the syntax? I mean how exactly you are importing ?

Comment: @import "compass/css3";

Answer (score 3):

**Try** **this:**

```
@import url('compass/css3.css');
```

Comment: @import url('./compass/css3.css');   I have tried this in my machine it is working fine. If still not working please share more code